# AngularJS directives misunderstanding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I am trying to create a basic app with a header & main view, using directives. Initially I had the directive in a separate file, but have moved it into app.js to eliminate a problem.

I have tried a few different things:

- `<app-header>` & `<div=app-header>`
- Changing templateUrl to template:"Test header"
- Chaining the directive and app.directive

My index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app="simpleLoginApp">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title> Simple Login </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div app-header></div>
        <main role="main" ng-view></main>

        <script src="resources/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="resources/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

My app.js:

```
    var app = angular.module('simpleLoginApp', ['ngRoute'])

    .directive('app-header', function() {
      return {
        templateUrl: '/header/header.html'
      };
    })

    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/login', {
                templateUrl: '/login/login.html',
                controller: 'LoginCtrl'
            })
    }]);
```

Header.html

```
    <header>
            <h1>HEADER</h1>
    </header>
```

Comment: A question or a problem description would help. So far it's mostly just a statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you register your directive.  When defining a directive, you should use camel case, e.g. `appHeader` instead of `app-header`.  When using it in a template you should use the dashes as you've done.  You can see the documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) under the Normalization heading

In short change

```
.directive('app-header', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: '/header/header.html'
  };
})
```

to

```
.directive('appHeader', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: '/header/header.html'
  };
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Header.html just needs to be:

```
<h1>HEADER</h1>
```

Your directive needs to be:

```
.directive('appHeader', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E', //This will make your directive work as an element  
    templateUrl: '/header/header.html'
  };
})
```

Then you simply include your directive in the code as an element:

```
<app-header></app-header>
```

Note that the above will only work with the words "Header" - you probably want some way to define different headers, right?

```
.directive('appHeader', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
        headerText: '='; 
    }
    restrict: 'E', //This will make your directive work as an element  
    templateUrl: '/header/header.html'
  };
})
```

Then in your code:

```
<app-header header-text="lol this is the content of my header ^_^"></app-header>
```

This way, the directive is reusable.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply! I get no errors, but I still see no header when i load the server :( When I inspect the element i see `<app-header></app-header>== $0`

Comment: Check out Dustin's reply - he is right, it won't work without that. I edited my answer to account for what he said as well.